# Starting from scratch

Tags: html, css, tags, css-position, element

I'm about to start a website from scratch.

I already run into my first problems.

Where do I start with the positioning of the elements?
body? html?

I started with ...

```
* { border: 1px solid white;}
```

to help me orientate, but the problem was that the border right and bottom where larger than my screen, so scrollbars appeared.

Why? I mean I could hide them via `overflow: hidden`, but why doesn't the border fit to my screen?

The other thing is, what element is the "first one" that should be positioned? html? body?

My thought is after the first one is positioned as I want a can position all the others within that one.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. Click the `<>` snippet editor and add HTML and CSS to show what you have tried so far. We cannot guess why your HTML does not fit unless you SHOW the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your content i can't say why it's larger than your screen mostly because the content is too large that is the reason. However for positioning always use body tag if not the first div tag inside your body(it completely depends upon on your design)

Answer (score 0):

You learn about basic html and css tutorial. 
first you know what's your screen resolution and then fix your body width using css.